In VBA how to prevent localization from being applied to Boolean values?
Question
How can I adjust my VBA or their environment so that when they run the code the SQL statement will read
UPDATE Properties_FloorTraits SET [Floor Accessible] = True WHERE [Property ID] = 'B3237' AND [Floor] = 35;

Instead of
UPDATE Properties_FloorTraits SET [Floor Accessible] = Vrai WHERE [Property ID] = 'B3237' AND [Floor] = 35;

Background
I have a new issue in a VBA legacy tool for a brand new user. The tool has been in production for years with minimal issues but now this new user is experiencing problems with almost every action they do.
I am assuming that they have requested for a French environment and that is causing my issue. I assume this because they are French, a new user on a new computer and I have never seen this issue before.
Relevant Information

Private Function GetUpdateFloorAccessibilityCommand() As String
    GetUpdateFloorAccessibilityCommand = "UPDATE Properties_FloorTraits SET [Floor Accessible] = " & IsFloorAccessible() & " " & _
                      "WHERE [Property ID] = '" & ManageSpaces.Id & "' AND [Floor] = " & ManageSpaces.Floors(ManageSpaces.FloorIdx, 1) & ";"
End Function

Public Function IsFloorAccessible() As Boolean
    IsFloorAccessible = ManageSpaces.FloorAccessible.Value = "Yes"
End Function



IsFloorAccessible = IIf(ManageSpaces.FloorAccessible.Value = "Yes", "True", "False") and change the return type from boolean  to string?   Or if you need that boolean for other purposes create a function to translate a boolean to (English) string value "True/False" instead of relying on the default string representation.

I did something similar to that but directly in the method creating the query. I'm more worried that somewhere else in the code I missed another reference written differently where this issue would prop up.

Not sure there's much you can do without a code review for other potential instances of the same problem...  As long as the user has a French environment you will get the default "toString" behavior.

I don't understand... Why do you check a boolean value for "Yes" instead of True?

Maybe use -1 and 0. What is ManageSpaces.FloorAccessible? Why would you test for a string "Yes"?

ManageSpaces is a Form. FloorAccessible is a drop down with values "Yes" and "No".

The underlying problem is that this code is using string concatenation to construct SQL queries. That's bound to lead to problems (localization problems being a major one, but others potentially popping up as well). See How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access? on how to avoid it properly

Construct combobox so its value is -1 or 0 but user sees "Yes" and "No".
